# I installed the latest version of Android Studio. I encountered error while syncing gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I installed the latest version of Android Studio. I encountered the following error while syncing gradle:Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.2/gradle-4.1.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project.
I disabled  'offline mode' and when i synced again while downloading 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.2/gradle-4.1.2.pom'. This error occurred:
{
"errors" : [ {
"status" : 404,
"message" : "Could not find resource"
} ]
}
please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Is your computer connected to the internet? This error happens when you are offline.

Comment: Yes, my computer is connected to the Internet.

Comment: Ok, you could try to `Clean` and `Rebuild` the project from the `Build` menu or, if that doesn't work, `Invalidate caches/restart...` from the `File` menu of Android Studio

Comment: Dear luca_999 thank you for your valuable guidance.

Comment: The actual problem is with "bintray" repo. This repo is shut down now. Also replace "Jcenter" with mavenCentral().

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I tried to Clean and Rebuild the project but it didn't work. Also tried the Invalidate cashes/restart from File menu too, it didn't work. I changed the repositories in `build.gradle` to this:

```
repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {url"https://jitpack.io"}
        jcenter()
        //mavenCentral()
    }
```

Tried without and with these changes too but the problem still not solved. Any other help?
And I used different network connections with and without VPNs , again, was not helpful.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. It is because, "Jcenter and Bintray" are shut down now.
We need to find an alternative for this.

Replaced Jcenter() with MavenCentral() in build.gradle. But the issue remains the same.